# how to pass schema name dynamically during run time when i have same table in schemas

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two different schemas say schema1 and schema2, both the schema has the same tables say table.
so the structure is like schema1.table and schema2.table

in my java entity class, I have created the entity for the table, so how should I pass the schema name dynamically at run time to my entity class.

Note: I am not using JPA entity manager, am using JPA repositories.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry that I have no enough reputation to comment. If you are looking for a runtime approach, you have to implement a database schema multitenancy pattern.